# Attaching a file to a new calendar event causes the vertical scroll bar to disappear

Tags: calendar, attachments

When I create a new calendar event and when I attach a file the vertical scroll bar disappears.

**Edit**

Providing a screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/demolh.png/.

Funny thing is this happens in MOSS 2007 as well. Is there something that I need to enable or edit?

Comment: I think we're going to need a bit more information to go off of.  Is the site using any custom master pages and or css?

Comment: @PirateEric: No the site is not using any custom master page or css. I am using the default one.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, I still don't see what scroll bar is missing

Comment: Thanks Chandra, I've reopened your question and added the info from your comment to the question. Could you provide us with a "before" picture that shows the scroll bar? I'm having trouble seeing where the scroll bar would be. Also, are you trying to make the scroll bar be visible at all times?

Comment: Dear All, there should be a scroll bar at the left side of the pop-up page. But after I click on attach item option and attach a file the scroll bar disappears. This is the image before I attach an item to the new event http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/beforer.png/ and this is the image after I attach the item http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/demolh.png/. And as you can see the scroll bar is gone......Hope the information helps

Comment: Please add any additional information into the main body of your question, this makes it far more readable.